# Convert ISBN10 to ISBN13 on insert and update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert ISBN10 to ISBN13 with a trigger. I am having problems with my code and it's not working (Error code below). Also if you have any idea on making the ISBN13 when value at the back of the ISBN10 is 'X' feel free to give suggestions

The trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER ISBN
ON Library.Book
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED) > 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @isbn VARCHAR(13),
    @i INT = 1,
    @x INT = 0,
    @isbn13 varchar(13),
    @id INT,
    @name VARCHAR(200)

    DECLARE Upda CURSOR
    FOR SELECT Id,Isbn,Name
        FROM inserted

    OPEN Upda

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM Upda
    INTO @id,@isbn,@name


    WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        IF Len(@isbn) = 10
        BEGIN
            SET @isbn13 = '978' + LEFT(@isbn,9)
            WHILE @i <= 9
            BEGIN
            SELECT @x = @x + (SUBSTRING(@isbn,@i,1)* CASE WHEN @i % 2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 3 END)
            SELECT @i = @i + 1
            END

            SELECT @x = 10 - (@x % 10)
            
            SELECT @isbn13 = @isbn13 + CONVERT(CHAR(1), @x)
            INSERT INTO Library.Book(Id,Isbn,Name)
            VALUES(@id,@isbn13,@name)
        END
    END
END
```

And with that code if I try to insert new values in the table I get an error "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'Library.Book'. The duplicate key value is (4)" on row Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Procedure ISBN, Line 39

```
INSERT INTO Library.Book (Id, Isbn, Name)
VALUES (1, '9512913151', 'Book 1'),
       (2, NULL, 'Book 2'),
       (3, '9781119245513', 'Book 3'),
       (4, '951884111X','Book 4')
```

So the goal is that the Id 4 will become ISBN13 and when I update the Id 2 value ISBN it should automatically convert to ISBN13.

```
UPDATE Library.Book
SET Isbn = '0321189566'
WHERE Id = 2
```

Comment: You really need to move to a set based approach for that `TRIGGER`. Putting a `CURSOR` like that is going to be awful for performance when you have an `INSERT`/`UPDATE` that effects more than a single row.

Comment: Hi @Steffe30 - you seem to be missing some known results / test data - i.e. given this ISBN 10 its value XX as an ISBN 13 is YY.  Then you'll be in a better position to see whether what you are doing is working correctly or not.  Also please update your question with what "not working means" ..

Comment: Wait, there's a `WHILE` in that `CURSOR` too! OK, that needs to go as well. That's a loop within a loop; that'll perform that **** I'm afraid. SQL is a set based language, it's awful at iteration like that.

Comment: As for *why* it's failing, it's because you're `INSERT`ing the data into ` Library.Book` again your `TRIGGER`, not updating the value. But that doesn't change any of my point above; you **need** to fix that trigger's iteration.

Comment: My suggestion. First, you're in over your head. Triggers require more than a basic understanding of tsql. Get help, get knowledge, get experience. More importantly, stop accommodating poor coding practices. The database should NOT be accepting bad information and then "clarifying" it afterwards. Only valid data should be allowed, anything else should be rejected. The insertion process should be responsible for correcting / adjusting the isbn values. It is bad practice to insert "X" into a table but not be able to find that same value immediately afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, there are several problems with your `TRIGGER`. As I talk about in the comments, muliple times, it's not set based, which is a huge issue. This could easily bring your database to a crawl when you are processing even a few rows; as you're looping on both the rows and then *each* character in the ISBN. For just 100 rows you have 1,200 iterations! That needs fixing.

Let's create some sample data first:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Book (ID int PRIMARY KEY,
                       ISBN char(13),
                       [Name] varchar(50));
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Book (Id, Isbn, Name)
VALUES (1, '9512913151', 'Book 1'),
       (2, NULL, 'Book 2'),
       (3, '9781119245513', 'Book 3'),
       (4, '951884111X','Book 4');
```

Now I did a Google to find out what the algorithm is to convert an ISBN10 to an ISBN13 and found this [article](https://isbn-information.com/convert-isbn-10-to-isbn-13.html).

For the data you have, that led me to this **set based** solution:

```sql
WITH ISBN AS(
    SELECT ID,
           '978' + LEFT(B.ISBN,9) AS ISBN12
    FROM dbo.Book B
    WHERE LEN(B.ISBN) = 10)
SELECT I.ID,
       I.ISBN12 + RIGHT(10-SUM(CASE V.I % 2 WHEN 0 THEN TRY_CONVERT(int,SS.C) * 3 ELSE TRY_CONVERT(int,SS.C) END)%10,1) AS ISDBN13
FROM ISBN I
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12))V(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(I.ISBN12,V.I,1)))SS(C)
GROUP BY I.ID, I.ISBN12;
```

Now, the problem here is the `'X'`. According to another Google, `'X'` means `10`, so we can update the above to handle that:

```sql
WITH ISBN AS(
    SELECT ID,
           '978' + LEFT(B.ISBN,9) AS ISBN12
    FROM dbo.Book B
    WHERE LEN(B.ISBN) = 10)
SELECT I.ID,
       I.ISBN12 + RIGHT(10-SUM(CASE V.I % 2 WHEN 0 THEN N.I * 3 ELSE N.I END)%10,1) AS ISDBN13
FROM ISBN I
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12))V(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(I.ISBN12,V.I,1)))SS(C)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CASE SS.C WHEN 'X' THEN 10 ELSE TRY_CONVERT(int,SS.C) END)) AS N(I)
GROUP BY I.ID, I.ISBN12;
```

Finally, then, we can put that into a `TRIGGER`...

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER Book_ISDB10_to_ISBN13 ON dbo.Book
FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS

    WITH ISBN AS(
        SELECT i.ID,
               '978' + LEFT(i.ISBN,9) AS ISBN12
        FROM inserted i
        WHERE LEN(i.ISBN) = 10),
    ISDN13 AS(
        SELECT I.ID,
               I.ISBN12 + RIGHT(10-SUM(CASE V.I % 2 WHEN 0 THEN N.I * 3 ELSE N.I END)%10,1) AS ISDN13
        FROM ISBN I 
             CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12))V(I)
             CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(I.ISBN12,V.I,1)))SS(C)
             CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CASE SS.C WHEN 'X' THEN 10 ELSE TRY_CONVERT(int,SS.C) END)) AS N(I)
        GROUP BY I.ID, I.ISBN12)
    UPDATE B
    SET ISBN = I.ISDN13
    FROM dbo.Book B
         JOIN ISDN13 I ON B.ID = I.ID;

GO
```

Notice I only update rows that *need* to be as well, not *all* of them.

Then we can `TRUNCATE` the table, and check the data:

```sql
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.Book;
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Book (Id, Isbn, Name)
VALUES (1, '9512913151', 'Book 1'),
       (2, NULL, 'Book 2'),
       (3, '9781119245513', 'Book 3'),
       (4, '951884111X','Book 4');
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Book;
GO
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=6aaf35e0caeaac5c6410a8ddb18d009a)

Quoted from [isbn-information.com](https://isbn-information.com) article for completion:

> ### The Conversion Of ISBN-10 to ISBN-13
>
> Here's what we're going to do in the seven steps below:
>
> - take the 10 digit ISBN (10 digits)
> - drop the last character (9 digits)
> - tack on "978" to the front (12 digits)
> - calculate a new check digit and tack it on to the end (13 digits)
>
> Here we go.
>
> Example starting ISBN-10
>
> ```
> 1861972717
> ```
>
> 1. Take all 10 digits of the ISBN-10 and drop the final digit - just forget it. The final digit is a check digit that was only good for the 10-digit ISBN - we need to calculate a new one for the new 13-digit ISBN in steps 3 to 6 below. (What's the check digit all about? Details on the ISBN Check Digit page.)
>
>    ```
>    186197271
>    ```
> 2. Prepend the digits "978" onto the front of the nine digits. (Why 978? See the ISBN-13 page.)
>
>    ```
>    978186197271
>    ```
> 3. In this and the next three stages we have to calculate the new check digit to append to the twelve digits from step 2. We take each of the 12 digits from step 2, one by one, and multiply them by a number. We multiply the first digit by 1, the second digit by 3, the third digit by 1 again, the fourth digit by 3 again, and so on, alternating 1 and 3 until we get to the twelfth digit.
>
>    Here's what I got. Did you get the same?
>
>    ```
>    9 x 1 = 9
>    7 x 3 = 21
>    8 x 1 = 8
>    1 x 3 = 3
>    8 x 1 = 8
>    6 x 3 = 18
>    1 x 1 = 1
>    9 x 3 = 27
>    7 x 1 = 7
>    2 x 3 = 6
>    7 x 1 = 7
>    1 x 3 = 3
>    ```
> 4. Now add up all 12 of the answers you got in step 3.
>
>    ```
>    9 + 21 + 8 + 3 + 8 + 18 + 1 + 27 + 7 + 6 + 7 + 3 = 118
>    ```
> 5. Take the answer from step 4 and perform a modulo 10 division. A modulo 10 division is also called casting out 10s. It's just the remainder when you do a whole number division (as opposed to a decimal division where you expect a decimal fraction answer).
>
>    118 mod 10 = 8. 118 divided by 10 = 11 remainder 8. We're interested in just the remainder.
>
>    ```
>    8
>    ```
> 6. Final step of calculating the check digit for a ISBN-13. Take the result from step 5. If it is zero, then the check digit is zero. If the result from step 5 isn't zero, then subtract the result from step 5 from the number 10. That result is the check digit.
>
>    ```
>    10 - 8 = 2.
>    ```
> 7. Final step of converting our ISBN-13 from the ISBN-10 is to append the check digit arrived at in step 6 onto the end of the 12 digits we arrived at in step 2.
>
>    ```
>    9781861972712
>    ```

Comment: Actually you don't need to bother about `X`. That is the check digit for `ISBN10`. It is not taking into consideration in the process of converting to `ISBN13`

Comment: You're right, @Squirrel . Ahh well, it's in there now... Lol

Comment: one small thing... why the CTE is named `ISDN13` instead of `ISBN13` :)

Comment: @Squirrel I kept on calling it `ISDB` when i was coding it... I think that (fixing) the aliasing is the smallest part of the legwork that the OP can do here, considering the amount of Googling I had to do to work out the requirements.

Comment: Well thank you that looks way more harder then I thought it would :D! I will have to look and learn that code so that I can 100% understand what it does.

Comment: *"that looks way more harder then I thought it would"* This irony then that it's more succinct that your attempt, @Steffe30 . ;)